# Renaming the index.html on Google App Engine

Tags: javascript, angular, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Ok, let me 1st come clean.  I mistakenly added a 365d expiration date to my `index.html` file.  I've now made a change to a JS file, which changed the name of the import in my `index.html` and now it's trying to import the wrong file. Oops.

So I'm thinking let's change the name of the default file name to something else that isn't cached.

### What I have now

In my Angular project, I've changed all the building settings so now my `index.html` file is named `main.html`.  The even the file itself is named `main.html`, and checking in my dist folder, there is no `index.html` only a `main.html`.

I have hosted the site on Google App Engine and this is the command I used to deploy after building.

`gcloud app deploy app.yaml --quiet --project=<project-name>`

Here is my `app.yaml`

```
api_version: 1

env: standard
runtime: python27
service: <service-name>
threadsafe: yes


handlers:

- url: /(.*\.(css|eot|gz|html|ico|js|map|png|jpg|jpeg|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|pdf|gif))
  static_files: dist/browser/\1
  upload: dist/browser/(.*\.(css|eot|gz|html|ico|js|map|png|jpg|jpeg|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|pdf|gif))
  expiration: "365d"

- url: /.*
  static_files: dist/browser/main.html
  upload: dist/browser/main.html
  secure: always
  expiration: "0s"

skip_files:
 ## bunch of files
```

### Problem:

It seems like Google is still serving up `index.html`, though to be honest I'm not really sure how to check.  How do tell it to serve up the `main.html` as the default file?

---

### Edit 1

When I visit `www.my-domain.com` it still serves up the old `index.html`.  But when I go to the `<project>.appspot.com` (the google URL) which I haven't been to and I'm guessing neither has anyone else in quite some time, (not cached) it works.

It seems like Changing the name of the `index.html` doesn't matter to the cache providers only that they are GETing data from `/`.  I have asked another related question about redirecting to another URL `/` => `app`

([Redirect base `/` path to folder in Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58703527/redirect-base-path-to-folder-in-google-app-engine))

---

### Edit 2

Using the technique here (https://www.maxlaumeister.com/blog/how-to-use-google-app-engine-as-a-free-redirect-server/) I was able to get a redirect working so when the user loads `/` the server redirects to `/app/`.  This works great, for the uncached `appspot.com` url.  My custom domain still doesn't work.

I'm pretty sure some middle man (ISP or Tier 1 provider) is cacheing the entire GET request to `/`.  Not just `index.html` or the server response to `/`

I'm not sure what other ideas I have.  Are there any other ways to bust this caching?

Answer (score 1):

> **You can achieve this by modifying your `app.yaml` file and add a handler as in the example shown below:**

**Serving `main.html` here:**

```
handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: app/main.html
  upload: app/main.html
```

**Serving `index.html`, instead:**

```
handlers:
    - url: /
      static_files: app/index.html
      upload: app/index.html
```

**Where `app` is the folder in which `index.html` and `main.html` are located in. You may have something that looks different.**

Comment: I posted my app.yaml, I have already modified that to serve `main.html` but that didn't seem to do anything

Comment: Hi @MindlessRouse. Please notice that I am using `url: /` for the root URL (/), whereas `url: /.*` would be for all other URLs. More info is can be found **[here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_script)**. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I tried what you mentioned.  The reason I have `url: /.*` is because this is an Angular Single page app.  Without the star, if you deeplink into some page then you get a 404.

Comment: Ignoring the SPA needs, I did try the `url: /` and it seemed to still be serving the old `index.html`

Comment: As you mentioned, it also worked for me when using `appspot.com` Google's domain. I just realized now you are using a custom domain. Have you tried deploying a new version of your App Engine? When performing updates in your static files, changes will not be applied right away, due to **[propagation and cache](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#static_cache_expiration)** reasons. Also since I saw your edited question, you can **[override routing rules using](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/reference/dispatch-yaml)** `dispatch.yaml` file

Comment: Through trying lots of different ideas I have redeployed maybe 40 times.  On recheck this morning it is still cached.  This is where my mistake error came in.  I set the `expiration` for `url: /` in my app.yaml to 30 days.  I think the ISPs/CDNs/Whatever are holding on to my old index.html file and serving it to users.

Comment: I looked into the `dispatch.yaml` (I used this to redirect API requests).  I deployed a new service.  Where I was using default, I changed to newui.  I then redirected my base url `*.my-domain.com/*` to this new Service.  But that didnt work.

Comment: I think this is expected as it says on the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#static_cache_expiration): After a file is transmitted with a given expiration time, there is generally no way to clear it out of intermediate caches, even if the user clears their own browser cache. Re-deploying a new version of the app will not reset any caches. I haven't tested it on a custom domain myself. However, my hypothesis is that you may have to wait until the static cache is flushed out from your since it worked for both of us on our `appspot.com` domain.

Comment: This is what I was fearful of.  Waiting 30 days is pretty much unacceptable for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201891/discussion-between-sllopis-and-mindlessrouse).

Answer (score 0):

Change `value` for `index` **index.html** to **main.html** in **angular-cli.json**