# Redirect base `/` path to folder in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have an Angular site hosted in Google App Engine using the Python27 runtime in a standard env.

When someone visits my site `www.site.com` I want them automatically redirected to `www.site.com/app`.  For reasons, I cannot do within the `index.html` file.

(For an explanation why and reason for doing so, see this question [Renaming the index.html on Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58687038/renaming-the-index-html-on-google-app-engine))

In my app, I have tried things like

```
- url: /
  mime_type: text/html
  static_files: dist/app/index.html
  upload: dist/app/index.html
  expiration: 0s
```

For reasons that seem obvious to me now, this won't work as it does not rewrite the URL for the user.  It doesn't seem there is a solution to rewrite rules similar to and `.htaccess` file.  I understand this is arguably a better solution but not what I need to do right now.

Is there a setting in the Google App Engine that I am missing?

Is there an attribute in the `app.yaml` file that I am overlooking?

Thank you for your help

Comment: It is a feature request opened [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/35901019)

Comment: Oh man, opened in 2016.  That doesn't fill me with hope :/

Comment: maybe this workaround is helpful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42777860/http-to-https-redirection-on-app-engine/42991054#42991054)